R: Creating Continuous Age in Years from DOB and Survey Date
I am currently working in R and trying to calculate continuous age at the start of specific surveys. I have two columns: START and DOB.
START               DOB    
5/26/2024 10:33      10/25/1991   
7/15/2024 12:52      5/15/1996  

Both START and DOB are in character format as they are downloaded from an online survey portal. I am wondering how I can take START date so that it doesn’t include the time and will then calculate continues age in years.
I’ve tried to model my code after those found for converting dates and those for converting characters to dates, but have been so far unsuccessful. I am using the lubricate package, but can’t seem to figure out where I am going wrong.
> df$BSTART<-as.Date(df$BSTART)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I have tried multiple codes that adjust the types of variables but none will accept the change for START to datetime

as.Date(df$BSTART, format = "%m/%d/%Y") or lubridate::mdy(df$BSTART). You mention that you've "tried to model my code" and you've "tried multiple codes." It would be helpful to include those in your question so we can help untangle any misunderstandings or perceive if there's anything unexpected about your data.

The help at ?as.Date notes that "The default formats follow the rules of the ISO 8601 international standard which expresses a day as "2001-02-03". Your example data in both columns is in american mdy order.
